# content of LinerarLayout has not the wanted width

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hintergrund"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/display"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"          
        />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="bla"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/ergebnis"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hello, I'm new to Android development and especially to XML.

I want the EditText and the Button to fill the screen width but when running the code above the emulator shows that they are centered but only filling approximately half of the screens width. How can I change that and what am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: In your second `LinearLayout` you set the background as `@drawable/display` - does the image actually fill the screen width?

Comment: The background diplay.png is a stretchable .9.png file, so I guess it should stretch to the screen dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question wasn't clear. What do you see in the layout? Does the background drawable stretch to fit the screen or not? I was asking because the first `LinearLayout` is the parent of the second `LinearLayout` which is the parent of the `EditText`, `Button` and `TextView`. Layout parameters such as `match_parent` refer directly to the 'parent'. If your background drawable isn't stretching to full screen width then it's perhaps because the second (inner) `LinearLayout` is being auto-sized to the drawable and might explain the problem with the `EditText` and `Button` widths.

Comment: The background image does stretch, but there are small margins to the borders of the screen, which are filled with the image of the outer LinearLayout. You can see it on this screenshot
[link](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/7080/ohnetitela.png)

Comment: OK, the small gaps at the top and sides of the `@drawable/display` are caused because the outer `LinearLayout` (as with all views) has `padding` set probably defaulting to 3dp or perhaps 4 or 5. You can reduce that to 0dp if you want to get rid of those gaps. Unfortunately I don't have any further ideas on your problem with the `EditText` and `Button`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroun="@drawable/hintergrund"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/display"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bla" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ergebnis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm afraid it does not work for me. First I changed my code manually and tried it, it didn't work. Then I also copied your complete code but the result was the same. Is it possible that there is something with the background display.png? It is a stretchable .9.png file...